# eclipselink how-to use expression anyOf with cache?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

When using eclipselink 2.5.2 expression language like this:

```
    ReadAllQuery raqEmp = new ReadAllQuery(Employee.class);
    raqEmp.conformResultsInUnitOfWork();
    raqEmp.setInMemoryQueryIndirectionPolicy(new InMemoryQueryIndirectionPolicy(InMemoryQueryIndirectionPolicy.SHOULD_TRIGGER_INDIRECTION));
    ExpressionBuilder ebEmp = new ExpressionBuilder();
    Expression exprAnyOf = ebEmp.anyOf("contacts");
    Expression exp = exprAnyOf.get("customer").equal(cus).and(exprAnyOf.get("days_visted").equal(5));
    raqEmp.setSelectionCriteria(exp);
```

I get all employees visited customer *cus* and all employees visited a custumer for five days. But I want of course all employees visited customer *cus* for five days. This happens only if the *contacts* are already instantiated before.

Thanks

Here are my Enities Employee, Contact and Customer:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="TKE_EMPLOYEE")
    public class Employee
    {
        public Employee()
        {
        }

        public Employee(String name)
        {
            super();
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        private long id;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee")
        private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

        private String name;

        public void addContact(Contact c)
        {
            if ( c != null )
            {
                this.contacts.add(c);
                c.employee = this;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "[" + name + "]";
        }
    }


    @Entity
    @Table(name="tke_Contact")
    public class Contact
    {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        private long id;

        @ManyToOne()
        public Customer customer;

        @ManyToOne()
        public Employee employee;

        public int days_visted;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return customer + " <-> " + employee + ", days_visted=" + days_visted;
        }
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name="tke_Customer")
    public class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
        }

        public Customer(String name)
        {
            super();
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        private long id;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
        private List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

        private String name;

        public void addContact(Contact c)
        {
            if ( c != null )
            {
                this.contacts.add(c);
                c.customer = this;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[" + name + "]";
        }
    }
```

Generate three Contacts:

Con1: Bob, 5 days, CompA

Con2: Paul, 10 days, CompA

Con3: Paul, 5 days, CompB

```
    public class Main
    {
        private static Employee getNewEmployee(String name, UnitOfWork uow)
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee(name);
            uow.registerNewObject(emp);
            return emp;
        }

        private static Customer getNewCustomer(String name, UnitOfWork uow)
        {
            Customer cus = new Customer(name);
            uow.registerNewObject(cus);
            return cus;
        }

        private static Contact getNewContact(UnitOfWork uow)
        {
            Contact con = new Contact();
            uow.registerNewObject(con);
            return con;
        }

        private static ReadAllQuery getNewReadAllQuery(Class<?> c)
        {
            ReadAllQuery raq = new ReadAllQuery(c);
            raq.conformResultsInUnitOfWork();
            raq.setInMemoryQueryIndirectionPolicy(new InMemoryQueryIndirectionPolicy(InMemoryQueryIndirectionPolicy.SHOULD_TRIGGER_INDIRECTION));
            return raq;
        }

        private static void doInit()
        {
            UnitOfWork uow = DBSessionProvider.getInstance().getClientSession().acquireUnitOfWork();

            Employee bob = getNewEmployee("Bob", uow);
            Employee paul = getNewEmployee("Paul", uow);

            Customer compA = getNewCustomer("CompA", uow);
            Customer compB = getNewCustomer("CompB", uow);

            Contact con1 = getNewContact(uow);
            con1.days_visted = 5;
            bob.addContact(con1);
            compA.addContact(con1);


            Contact con2 = getNewContact(uow);
            con2.days_visted = 10;
            paul.addContact(con2);
            compA.addContact(con2);


            Contact con3 = getNewContact(uow);
            con3.days_visted = 5;
            paul.addContact(con3);
            compB.addContact(con3);

            uow.commit();
            uow.release();
        }

        private static void doMain()
        {
            UnitOfWork uow = DBSessionProvider.getInstance().getClientSession().acquireUnitOfWork();

            //Init all contacts (!)
            ReadAllQuery raqCon = getNewReadAllQuery(Contact.class);
            Vector<Contact> resultSetCon = (Vector<Contact>) uow.executeQuery(raqCon);
            System.out.println(resultSetCon.size()); // -> 3

            //Read Customer CompA
            ReadAllQuery raqCompA = getNewReadAllQuery(Customer.class);
            ExpressionBuilder ebCompA = new ExpressionBuilder();
            raqCompA.setSelectionCriteria(ebCompA.get("name").equal("CompA"));
            Vector<Customer> resultSetCompA = (Vector<Customer>) uow.executeQuery(raqCompA);
            Customer compA = resultSetCompA.firstElement();

            //Read all Employees, visited CompA for 5 days -> only Bob via Con1
            ReadAllQuery raqEmp = getNewReadAllQuery(Employee.class);
            ExpressionBuilder ebEmp = new ExpressionBuilder();
            Expression exprAnyOf = ebEmp.anyOf("contacts");
            Expression exp = exprAnyOf.get("customer").equal(compA).and(exprAnyOf.get("days_visted").equal(5));
            raqEmp.setSelectionCriteria(exp);
            Vector<Employee> resultSetEmp = (Vector<Employee>) uow.executeQuery(raqEmp);
            System.out.println(resultSetEmp.size()); // -> 2 but should be 1

            uow.release();
        }


        public static void main(String args[])
        {
    //      doInit();
            doMain();
        }
```

Look at doMain(): When conforming results in UnitOfWork, Paul is checked: Paul has Con2 to customer CompA and Con3 with 5 days visited, so Paul is taken into the resultset. That is wrong, only Bob should be in the resultset as of Con1. If the contacts are not instantiated before, Paul ist not known to the cache.

Comment: I don't quite understand the query or how it relates to caching. The results of the query in this case should not change regardless of contacts being instantiated or not, as while the conforming option may change the results, it should only do so if you have uncommited/flushed changes in your context.  Otherwise, the results from the SQL query would be accurate, and return you employees that have days_visted=5 and have visited your customer. If you want to know the employees that have visited your customer in 5 days, there isn't a way with what you've presented.

Comment: Hi Chris, >If you want to know the employees that have visited your customer in 5 days, there isn't a way with what you've presented.< sounds like my expression is wrong. How does it look correct?

Comment: Please have look to my edits.

Comment: I was mistaken: your edits make it more obvious that the expression seems fine. Try the latest version and turn EclipseLink logging on to see if/what is happening. Conforming 'should' only affect changes within the persistence unit and might not be needed as it seems it can't handle the 'and' clause in your example, treating it as an 'or' instead or not checking the condition on the specific contact. If it reproduces on the latest, file a bug.

Comment: This issue is present in eclipselink 2.7.0, bug is opened https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526546

Comment: Workaround would be to not use the conforming feature, and instead flush changes to the database in the current transaction if you suspect they might affect query results. With JPA, there is a RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork that can be used, though I've not accessed it outside of JPA so I can't provide an example.

Comment: There is a fix available for version 2.6.6, see [link] https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526546